# Processing textual inputs in the client side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Razor view engine, is there a way to get the values of input fields before posting the data to the server, processing them and then sending the processed data instead?

For example:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ViewPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
     @Html.TextBox("Field1")
     @Html.Hidden("Field2");
     <input type="submit" id="HiddenButton" value="Submit" style="display:none" />
     <input type="button" id="VisibleButton" value="Submit" />    
}
```

and now :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.ready(function() {
        $("#VisibleButton").click(function() {
             var Temp = $("#Field1").val()
             @{
                 // C# Area
                 Processing the Temp, by for example calling an extension method and
                 assigning the new value to the Hidden Field
              }
              $("#HiddenButton").trigger("click")
        })
     })
</script>
```

I'd like to do this , because I wanna encrypt a text before sending it to the server and I've already made my encryption method in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but the *processing* should happen on the client using javascript:

```
$("#VisibleButton").click(function() {
    var Temp = $("#Field1").val();

    // process Temp here using javascript
    Temp = 'some new value';

    // set the processed value back to the input field
    $("#Field1").val(Temp);

    $("form").submit();
});
```

If you want the processing to happen on the server for some reasons, you could send it as an AJAX request to a controller action:

```
$("#VisibleButton").click(function() {
    var temp = $("#Field1").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
        data: { value: temp },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#Field1").val(result);
            $("form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

And your controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string value)
{
    // do your processing here 
    value = "some new value";

    return Json(value);
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, I wanna use C# to process the value which I get by JS

Comment: C# runs on the server, javascript on the client. Once you realize this fundamental concept you will understand that what you are trying to achieve doesn't make much sense. I have updated my answer with an example using AJAX to send the value to the server for processing and returning the modified value back to the client.

Comment: The problem is to bypass the content filtering for some texts ("political stuff") on some internet connection, if the data is sent like that, it is simply blocked. So it needs to be encrypted on the client side.

Comment: Then the only way to achieve that is to do it purely on the client using javascript.

Comment: That seems to be tough but when a 530K says so, it really is the only way :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this..
There is no magic here since JS code runs on the client's end and C# code is located in the server.

You can always use https for an encrypted session.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use C# to perform client-side validation. That's because client-side validation runs on users browser which only understands JavaScript and Html generated earlier by your C# code on the server.

Like Darin said, If you want to perform the validation in C#, you have to do in on server-side. For that you have to perform an ajax call and interpret the result in JavaScript.

One way is to do this the way Darin' shown. The other is to use a MVC built-in mechanism described [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/5250/remote-validator-in-Asp-Net-mvc3-razor.aspx).